# Powershell Script incl. VBA Excel Macro

Tags: excel, vba, powershell

I want to write a Powershell Script, which opens a existing file and puts a macro in it.
Im searching and searching, but I found nothing.

My Code is:

```
$Word = New-Object -ComObject Word.Application
$Word.Visible = $true
$filepathagenda = "C:\Users\$Username\Desktop\Agenda.docx"
$Word.Documents.Open($filepathagenda)
```

The VBA code is:

```vb
Sub Macroname()
    Dim oTab As Table
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim Std As Double
    Dim Min As Double
    Dim Dauer As Double
    Dim Z As Double
    Dim ZInt As Double
    Dim ZDez As Double
    Dim Txt As String

    Set oTab = ActiveDocument.Tables(1)
    i = oTab.Rows.Count

    For x = 2 To i    
        On Error GoTo ErrorHandle:

        Std = CDbl(Left(oTab.Cell(x, 5), 2))
        Min = CDbl(Mid(oTab.Cell(x, 5), 4, 2))
        Txt = oTab.Cell(x, 4).Range.Text

        Dauer = CDbl(Left(oTab.Cell(x, 4), Len(Txt) - 2))

        If Min + Dauer < 60 Then
            oTab.Cell(x + 1, 5).Range.Text = Format(Std, "00") & ":" & Format(Min + Dauer, "00")
            oTab.Cell(x + 1, 5).Select
        Else
            Z = (Min + Dauer) / 60
            ZDez = Z - Int(Z)
            ZDez = ZDez * 60
            oTab.Cell(x + 1, 5).Range.Text = Format(Std + Int(Z), "00") & ":" & Format(ZDez, "00")
            oTab.Cell(x + 1, 5).Select
        End If

        GoTo NoError:

ErrorHandle:
    oTab.Cell(x + 1, 5).Range.Text = Format(Std, "00") & ":" & Format(Min, "00")
    oTab.Cell(x + 1, 5).Select
    Resume NoError:

NoError:
    Next x

Ende:
End Sub
```

How can i put a Macro into the file ? 
I just found some commands, where i can run a macro, but nothing about embedding a macro into a file like that.
After the Script is embed into the docx/docm File i want to run the macro in the file with:

```
$word.run("Macroname") 
$word.quit() exit application
```

Answer (score 2):

You're probably looking for the `.Import` [method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/import-method-vba-add-in-object-model) of the Word document.

`objDocumentObject.VBProject.VBComponents.Import(strFilePathAndName)`

Where `strFilePathAndName` is a reference to a text document containing your macro.

The following uses a `FileDialog` method to choose the Word document and insert the macro line-by-line as a string, but it could also be done by referencing a filename variable using the method above.

```
Sub AddMacroToWordDoc()
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
        .Show
        Dim appWord As Word.Application
        Set appWord = New Word.Application

        Dim docDocToAdjust As Word.Document
        Set docDocToAdjust = appWord.Documents.Open(Trim(.SelectedItems(1)))

        docDocToAdjust.VBProject.VBComponents("ThisDocument") _
            .CodeModule.AddFromString _
            "Sub Test()" & vbLf & _
            "  MsgBox ""It works""" & vbLf & _
            "End Sub"
    End With
End Sub
```

Of note, both of these methods require the file to be trusted before VBA code insertion will work (for obvious reasons).

Edit: If you're using this in VBA from another Microsoft product, you also need to have the Microsoft Word Object Library referenced.

Comment: @defjay91 - If my answer sufficiently answered your question, please [mark the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) as the solution (and upvote if you feel appropriate), so that the question appears as resolved for others browsing the site. Thanks!

Comment: Hi @SmrtGrunt, thanks for your help, but both are VBA Commands - right? I need a PS Solution. Or is that impossible? 

My Problem is:

I have a Agenda in OneNote
I want to export it as a Word Document
After export i want to run the Macro to calculate the times
And i want to do the most of the steps via script..

Comment: @defjay91 Those are the VBA commands, but as far as I know they are referencing the Windows OLE library, so there is probably a PS equivalent syntax.